# Visual Studio 2013-TFS Testing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

What kind of tests can be applied a program in Visual Studio 2013-TFS? I am new in testing field and my company uses TFS 2013. Can anyone suggest me some document or already applied tests document in TFS.

Thanks for supports in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can start with MSDN: [Testing the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could read the e-book from the Microsoft patterns & practices team, Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio 2012 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159345).

It gives a good introduction and understanding of how you can use visual studio and related tools to test software.

Even though it is written for 2012, almost everything still applies for TFS 2013.